# Codeigniter Image doesn't display

Tags: image, codeigniter-3

I'm having a big problem that I can't see or access my image 
it says

> 403 forbidden

here is my code

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/shop/grandes_img/<? $big_pic ?>">
```

I tried to change the htaccess file inside my project it did not work
I'm stuck here
please help

Edit:
When I add a directory from phpstorm I don't find it inside the project directory why?

Comment: Can you show us the directory structure how you are storing the images??

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/shop/grandes_img/chargement1.jpg

Comment: Can you show the `base_url` in config

Comment: $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: Add like this. `$config['base_url'] = "http://127.0.0.1/";

Comment: Can you tell me, is your project name `shop`??

Comment: Yes the name of my project is shop

Comment: I've updated my code in the answer. Please check

Comment: No it didn't work

Comment: @FirasJerbi you forgot the `echo` part : `<?php echo $big_pic ?>`

Comment: show your database table and foreach loop which use in show your pic

Answer (score 0):

Add this.

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://127.0.0.1/shop/";
```

then change your image source as below

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>grandes_img/<?php echo $big_pic ?>" >
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Can you tell me where is your folder  `grandes_img` located??

Comment: Did you inspect the image tag in the browser?? I've updated the code again in my answer.

Comment: the folder is in the root

Comment: You mean outside application folder??